# Working with SharePoint excel in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Which python 3.x module works well with excel files in Microsoft SharePoint?

I have tried Office365-REST-Python-Client, but it is not supporting python 3.7.1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us more specific information about what you want to do?

Maybe you can have a look to : [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) or [python-sharepoint](https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint) or [shareplum](https://github.com/jasonrollins/shareplum)

Comment: I wants to work with the data in excel sheets which is in sharepoint.